# Woocommerce - get Billing first name from checkout

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am developing a shipping plugin for Woocommerce and I am trying to get the value of the Billing first name field from the checkout page.From what I've tried until now, I think I should make the Ajax refresh kick in after each field is edited, not only the ones regarding the address.

I've put this in my functions.php:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'get_customer_details');
function get_customer_details($post_data){
    global $woocommerce;
    global $order;

    // Details you want injected into WooCommerce session.
    $details = array('billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_company', 'billing_email', 'billing_phone');

    // Parsing data
    $post = array();
    $vars = explode('&', $post_data);
    foreach ($vars as $k => $value){
        $v = explode('=', urldecode($value));
        $post[$v[0]] = $v[1];
    }

    // Populate the session
    foreach($details as $key){
        if(isset($post[$key]))
            $woocommerce->session->set($key, $post[$key]);
    } 
}
```

In my JS file I have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'input change', '#billing_first_name, #billing_last_name', function() {
                       jQuery( 'body' ).trigger( 'init_checkout' );          
        });
});
```

Now I can access the value of Billing first name with:

```
$woocommerce->session->get('billing_first_name');
```

and the ajax refresh kicks in after Billing first name is edited; the thing is that it DOES NOT update the value of Billing first name, and I would need it to do that.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: are you saying that it's not updating the `billing_first_name` input field value?

Comment: The billing_first_name value from the session updates only if I edit one of the address fields that start the ajax update(address, city, state).